# Отображение элементов управления картой

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Не могу настроить позиционирование элементов управления картой так, как мне удобно. Есть [мануал](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/controls-docpage/), все делаю по нему, но кнопка отображения пробок не позиционируется. В чем может быть причина?

```js
ymaps.ready(function(){
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [37.61691485505143, 55.7517318022522],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: ['default', 'routeButtonControl']
 });
  myMap.controls.add('trafficControl', {
    float: 'right',
    position: {
      top: '34px',
      right: '10px'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день, вы используете controls: ['default'] что означает, что у вас добавлены все дефолтные контролы на карту и контрол пробок тоже. Если вы хотите поменять местоположение контрола пробок, то правильней будет получить контрол пробок и задать ему позицию так: myMap.controls.get('trafficControl').options.set({position: {top: '34px',right: '10px'}})

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [37.61691485505143, 55.7517318022522],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: ['default', 'routeButtonControl']
  });
  myMap.controls.get('trafficControl').options.set({
    position: {
      top: '34px',
      right: '10px'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```